# Where does inline datasource (sqlcommand + connectionstring + parameters) compile to in ASP .net (its not in the ViewState)?

Tags: sql, compilation, location, inline

Where does inline datasource (sqlcommand + connectionstring + parameters) compile to in ASP .net (its not in the `ViewState`)?

So it's not in the HTML when I view the source of a page, and it is not the `ViewState` if I decompile it. So does it compile to the same location as the aspx.vb/ aspx.cs file?

Is there thus no differenct wrt security of using an inline piece of code in the aspx file,
than using the same query in the aspx.vb/cs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET inline code get compiled into dll to the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` Folder, see [ASP.net compiled dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508701/asp-net-compiled-dlls)

Although I would strongly recommend to not leave any inline code that has no formatting purpose, especially data access layers.

As for your concern about security, you inline-coded connection string is visible to anyone that have read access to the Web site folder, and to anyone that have read access to the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` Folder on the server, but, using IIS, it won't be accessible to anyone browsing your web site through http(s) protocol.